# htaccess rewrite to capture filepath and query string separately

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get 2 different parts of a url and use them in a rewrite but I can't get it to work

I'd like

```
http://example.com/account/test-page?h=1&t=2
http://example.com/account/test-page
```

to rewrite to

```
http://example.com/page.php?path=account/test-page&h=1&t=2
http://example.com/page.php?path=account/test-page
```

I've tried a dozen different ways - this is the latest one :

```
RewriteRule ^http:\/\/example.com\/([^\?.]*)[\?]?([^/]*)$     http://example.com/page\.php?url=$1&$2
```

but it doesn't work and I'm tearing my hair out !!

could someone tell me where I'm messing up please ?

Comment: Remove the domain name from RewriteRule's pattern.

Comment: Did you even take a _single_ look into the documentation? This does not look like...

Comment: when I do
 
`^([^\?.]*)[\?]?(.*)$ page\.php\?url=$1&$2`

it adds the first group as a GET var (account/test-page) but not the second group, the GET vars from the original string ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following rule instead:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The key, here, is the [`QSA` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), which appends in query string used to the query string already passed to `page.php`.

To be clear, a request made to `/account/test-page?h=1&t=2` will be internally rewritten as `/page.php?path=account/test-page&h=1&t=2`.

Comment: ahhh that's brilliant, works perfectly - I've been sweating over this one all day and I didn't know about the QSA flag
A thousand thanks !